# How to select every other xth row while keeping the first and last row

Tags: r

Assume we have the following data:

```
Measure         Value
2.00              8
2.9993544         1
2.9993925         8
2.9994541        15
2.9994957         4
2.9995287         1
2.9995569        12
2.9996014         1
2.9996418        13
2.9996768         1
2.9997152         3
3                21
```

I want to select every second row but keeping the first row and last row. The expected output would be:

```
Measure         Value
2.00              8
2.9993925         8
2.9994957         4
2.9995569        12
2.9996418        13
2.9997152         3
3                21
```

I tried the following with several data sets but it removes the last row:

```
df[seq(1, nrow(df), 2), ]
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Try `unique(c(seq(1, nrow(df), 2), nrow(df)))`

Answer (score 1):

Use vector recycling.

```
d[c(TRUE, FALSE) | (seq(NROW(d)) == NROW(d)),]
#    Measure Value
#1  2.000000     8
#3  2.999392     8
#5  2.999496     4
#7  2.999557    12
#9  2.999642    13
#11 2.999715     3
#12 3.000000    21
```